# System don't recognize ubuntu partition ""All boot options are tried. Press F4 key to recover."

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, system-installation

I just formatted my Samsung Ultrabook and installed Ubuntu 12.04 via USB using rufus to create the bootable USB (my ultrabook don't have a cd/dvd reader). The problem is, when the instalation finish and ask for a reboot, it skips the hdd boot and start via USB right away, and when I remove the USB it says "All boot options are tried. Press F4 key to recover..." Wich I suppose says that I don't have a valid OS installed in my HDD. I reinstalled in the same partition overwriting the former ubuntu installation (the live cd recognized the previous installation). Same problem. After that I followed the instructions from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows And the same happened. I don't know what to do, and I can't use my ultra anymore. Help pls!

EDIT: I tried installing Windows 7 in half my hdd. Everything ok. But when I installed Ubuntu in the other half, I can't access to any of them. At startup says: 
"error: file not found.
grub rescue>"
However, I can access both OS with the bootable Super Grub Disk in my pendrive. Using the Super Grub I managed to install Lilo in my Ubuntu partition. After installing Lilo, the computer booted normally only windows 7. With further google hunting I read that this can be a grub problem, and messed up with grub settings via terminal. After that I can't access any OS, neither I can get to boot with lilo (can't find config files).
Now I know it's a problem with the boot files, not the ubuntu partition. What can I do? Is there any other boot type that may work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I did it! It appears that the windows 7 boot don't recognize Ubuntu without help. I followed the steps from this page and everything went fine:
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/708852/all-boot-options-are-tried-after-updating-bios) article. I think this might help you. Cheers! Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did as the article says and still the same problem. Even formatted it again with the BIOS settings as mentioned.

Comment: After all of the google hunting, I could not find any other solution. This solution worked out for almost everyone. But I noticed that this problem only exists on Samsung laptops. Maybe you should check out their forums and try to get some help over there. I am sorry I was not much of a help to you :( . Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Yes you were help, thanks a lot. I will search other forums and options, and if I find a solution I will post it here.